# office 365 IMAP mailbox migration error: MigrationRecipientNotFoundException

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I have tried to do this migration twice now and I get the same error.

> Error: MigrationRecipientNotFoundException: A recipient wasn‎'t found for "orders@example.com" on the target. Create a recipient of the appropriate type for this migration on the target and try again.

I know that on my target (Exchange online server) I have an account named *orders@mydomain.com* and have an account named *orders@example.com* at the source. I have two domains, the default *example.net* and the *example.com*. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Issue had to do with the fact the even though the user was created in office 365, it didn't have a corresponding exchange mailbox. SOLVED!

Answer (score 3):

Issue had to do with the fact that even though the user was created in office 365, it didn't have a corresponding exchange mailbox.  By creating a mailbox for this Office 365 user the migration succeeded.